# Oracle Apex 5.1: Styling the Region Title

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have created a Login page using Oracle Apex 5.1 where the region template is "Login". I want my region title to be bold and also want to increase the size of the title text. How can I achieve this?

I am sorry if this question is very noob level question. I am new to Oracle Apex and have spent several hours to achieve this. Could anyone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use HTML in any text fields like titels, headers, region text etc.

```
<p><font size="20" face="verdana" color="green"><b>This is some text!</b></font></p>
```

Also you can put region static ID and make custom styling with CSS (in page Inline CSS or in ThemeRoller)

**Edit:**
Just simple example:
I have Colapsible region with static id: **reg** 
Region title is h2 elemnt in the Div so in inline CSS section put something like this:

```
#reg h2{
  color:red;
  font-style: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

Change color, size, style or delete some lines until you are happy with the result.
You can use many style properties like drop shadows, font type, margins, paddings etc.
Use google search for more about CSS styling.

Comment: Could you please explain me how to use custom styling? I have used your first approach. But this is making the region title longer.

Comment: Reduce size (size="20") until it fit your needs. About styling  It's a bit complex to be written in comment. Try to learn more about CSS and HTML beacause they will help you a lot in Apex.  if you have more specific problems feel free to ask!
Regards

Comment: Thank you for your help @Boris. I actually wanted to know the procedure of custom CSS styling. For example, where should I write the CSS or html code in the application to change the style of the region title.
I have used your first approach and it is okay. But it makes the region title in the page designer the whole code instead of only the title text.

Comment: In Page Designer click on the top Rendering window(exam:Page 554: Page Name). On the right tab (Page) find section Inline CSS. In this section you can put style of your elemnts. Lets asume you have region with id P0_SEARCH(name of this input is ID of the element)   #P0_SEARCH {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-radius: 3px !important;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  outline-width: 0;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

Comment: You can use files with css style uploaded to you application files. In this case use File's URL in CSS section. Other way is to open your Theme Roller from developer tollbar and write CSS directly in Custom CSS section.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great help @Boris. Now I am able to change the style of all the page items using your approach. But somewhere I may have done some mistake so I could not style my Region title using this approach although I have accomplished region title styling using another approach. 

In inline CSS section I have added this code:   
.t-Login-title {font-weight: bold; font-size: 24px;} 

Your help fully guided me find this solution.